# Where are the proxy settings for the Eclipse Codename One Plugin?

Tags: codenameone

I'm running Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0) with the Codename One 5.0 behind a Microsoft NTLM authenticating proxy.

With that I am able to install new Eclipse plugins but when I'm trying to update the Codename One libraries using Codename One Settings -> Basics -> Update Project Libs it displays a dialog titled Updating which ist apart from an OK button empty for some time and then it shows an exception which cannot be copied, not scrollable and thus cannot be seen completely:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I assume I need to tweak the proxy settings for the Codename One plugin separately, right? Where would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the simulator and update the proxy settings under the `Simulate` -> `Network` menu. Once you do that it will apply to everything.

Comment: The proxy is set in the Simulator and I am able to bring up Skins -> More.. but I cannot update the libraries

Comment: I tried it again. I am able to bring up the list of skins in the Simulator - so that seems to work. But I am unable to update the libraries through project properties -> CodenameOne -> CodenameOne Settings -> Basics -> Update Project Libs when behind the proxy at the company I'm working for currently. The proxy is a Microsoft NTLM proxy and it is a SSL Interception Proxy. Any hints how I could investigate this?

Comment: That might be a bug in the update framework, try running it from command line and passing proxy settings there https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-update-framework.html if this is the case we need to address this